# Return an array of arrays that contain objects with the same property where properties change dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, filtering

So I am creating a todo app where a user can add a new todo to the Database. It is then fetched and filtered into specific categories to be displayed on the UI.

I need to create an array of arrays where each array contains objects that share the same category. This is the code that the user receives from the database:

```
let initialTodos = [
         { id: 1, todo: "Buy milk.", complete: false, category: "Grocery" },
         { id: 1, todo: "Clean the cat box.", complete: false, category: "House" },
         { id: 1, todo: "Chips and salsa.", complete: false, category: "Grocery" },
         { id: 1, todo: "Finish Homework for DGM 3760", complete: false, category: "School" }
     ]
```

I need to filter it out into something like this:
EDIT: It needs to be in the format below. Nested Arrays.

```
let filtered = [
   [
      {id: 1, todo: "Buy Milk", complete: false, category: "Grocery"},
      {id: 1, todo: "Chips and salsa", complete: false, category: "Grocery"}
   ],
   [
      {id: 1, todo: "Clean the cat box.", complete: false, category: "House"}
   ],
   [
      {id: 1, todo: "Finish Homework for School", complete: false, category: "School"}
   ]
]
```

You can ignore the id on each of them. Remember that new unique categories will be added to the list so it can't be 'hard-coded' filtering on the categories.

This is as close as I got:

```
let initialFiltering = initalTodos.map(todo => [todo]);
    let filtered = [];
    for (let arr in initalTodos) {
        for (let filter in initialFiltering) {
            if (!initialFiltering[arr][filter]) { break }
            if(initalTodos[arr].category == initialFiltering[arr][filter].category) {
                let takenOut = initialFiltering[arr].filter(filter => filter.category === initalTodos[arr].category)
                if (filtered[0]) {
                    for (let deep in filtered) {
                        if (takenOut[0].category === filtered[deep].category) {
                            filtered[deep].push(...takenOut)
                        } else if (filtered[deep].includes(takenOut[0].category)) {break}
                        else {filtered.push(takenOut)} 
                    }
                } else {
                    filtered.push(takenOut)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(filtered)
    console.log(initalTodos)
    console.log(initialFiltering)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Been working on this for days...

Comment: Instead of nested arrays, I recommend you create an object whose keys are the category and values are an array of items.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Any code I might look at to get a good idea of how that might look?